# Express - why might a PUT request return 404 error when POST request operates as expected?

Tags: node.js, express

**Environment:** Node.js & Express

I am using an HTML form to submit data with a `POST` request and it works as expected.  However when I switched it to a `PUT` request I received a `404 error`.  In the address bar I get req.body from the form.

```
http://localhost:8080/save_register?email=test%40gmail.com&firstName=hello&lastName=world&phone=555-555-5555&password=11111&passwordConfirm=11111
```

Why might this be?  Below is a simplified version of my server using the `PUT` request.

From middleware.js file.

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.render('register');
});

router.put('/save_register', function(req, res) {

    // lets of processing req.body here...

    if(itWorked === true) {
        return res.redirect('/register_success');
    } else {
        res.render('register');
    }
});

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).render('page_not_found');
});
```

from register.ejs file.

```
<form action="/save_register" method="PUT">
```

In middleware.js when `router.put` is changed to `router.post` and in register.ejs `method="PUT"` is changed to `method="POST"` it works as expected.  I must be missing something obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: I don't think HTML forms support the PUT method.

Comment: @jfriend00 holy smokes based on this post I think you are right, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML forms do not support the method `PUT`, only `GET` and `POST`.  If you specify something other than a `GET` or a `POST` for the form method, then the browser treats it as a `GET` and thus that is why you see all the data being sent in the URL.

As you have discovered, there's a pretty good description here: [Why are there no PUT and DELETE methods on HTML forms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms).